# How long do food effects last?

Tags: powder

My poor H'ruth zealot - although very skilled in the culinary arts (Endure hunger, Butchery, Clean kill) - appears to have inherited a weakness to silver items from a recent meal. Now, this would not have been a problem since I can just unequip all the silver items... but here's the dilemma:

At the floor I am currently at (and 1 or 2 floors up & down), I have stumbled upon many many ghosts, and I fear that without my +7 silver spear, I might not be able to beat them. So, either I just run past them, or I try to fight them with a weapon that sears my hands.

I'm not entirely sure, but the trait was probably received from an Ice Devil (well, it's remains). There were many creatures present during that skirmish, but the Ice Devil was the only one to possibly be able to react to silver (as I know that zombies, grid bugs, luxes and more zombies dont usually do that).

So, for how long must I rest in my enclosed chamber in order for the weakness to silver to wear off, so I can once again wield my mighty spear and smite the innocent residents of... *ahem* ...the foul dwellers of this dungeon?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @Young Guilo no